Meaning of thing in "Addie is a very cheerful girl. That’s her thing."
I came across the following in a book named "The Nightmare Room #1: Don't Forget Me!" written by R. L. Stine (2001):

Addie is a very cheerful girl. That’s her thing.

I think the word thing is intended to convey that being cheerful is part of her personality. However, I could not find this usage for thing in dictionaries (for example in Merriam-Webster). I'm wondering what what is the meaning of thing here.
Edit:
Continuing reading the book, I came across a somehow similar usage of thing by the author:

From halfway down the stairs, I could see Mojo turn red. That’s just his thing. If you talk to him, he blushes.


I think it's an extension of definition 7.

As noted in the comment, "thing" (sense 7 in MW) can mean "speciality".  It is more normal to use this with a hobby or activity "Football is his thing".  So using it of a personality trait is unusual or marked.  It suggests that being cheerful is what Addie does that makes her distinctive from other people. It suggests that being cheerful is more a choice or hobby rather than just part of her nature.
Wiktionary has "custom or habit"  Kissing on the cheeks is a French thing. And you can understand this in these terms too.  Being cheerful is Addie's habit. A "thing" is the custom that is distinctive.  Just as cheek-kissing is typically and distinctively French, so being cheerful is distinctively and typical of Addie.
It also has 16 "One's routine or habits" doing my thing. Again this points to the notion that being cheerful was a choice, or perhaps a pretence.  Part of Addie's "personal brand" and not just an aspect of her personality.

Wiktionary has definition 16. (informal, used possessively, with "do") One's typical routine, habits, or manner.   " let me do my thing;  I'm here doing my thing"  That might be a little closer. I'm not sure that "do" is always used.

That's his|her thing in American English slang can mean "chosen or innate way of behaving".  Compare:

Addie is a very cheerful girl. That’s how she rolls.

To say this of someone can imply that the speaker feels the behavior is pretense.  She chooses to act that way.  I don't know the R.L. Stine story, but wouldn't be surprised to learn that Abbie is actually somewhat sad. But cheerfulness could be her natural disposition.
